# How could these token-strings be defined

Tags: c, command, token, c-preprocessor, instructions

My question is about the `#define` directive.
In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-define-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-160) we have:

**Syntax**

```
#define identifier token-string
#define identifier ( identifier, ... , identifier ) token-string
```

In the **remarks**, it is written:

> The token-string argument consists of a series of tokens, such as keywords, constants, or complete statements.

**My question** is how can keywords, constants, complete statements, instructions and commands be defined in C.

I already have an "empirical" idea of ​​what each of these are, but I am not able define them in words.

I would appreciate it if you guys could help me, and if possible, include some examples for better understanding.

Comment: You could continue reading the Microsoft documentation, e.g. [Elements of C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/elements-of-c?view=msvc-160) or browse the final drafts of the C standards at https://port70.net/~nsz/c/

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4 - Lexical elements. Everything is defined in terms of BNF grammar

Answer (score 1):

Test this out:

```
#define macro(A, B, C) A; B; C;
macro(int i=0, int x = i + 1, printf("%d\n", x));
//expands to: int i=0; int x = i + 1; printf("%d\n", x);
```

or

```
#define macro(Type, Id) Type##Id
macro(int, array) //expands to: intarray
```

or

```
#define macro(X) #X
macro(x + y) //expands to: "x + y"
```

As you can see, you can pass all sort of things as argument to a 'function like macro'.

**More Info:**

- [Preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor)
- [Replacing text macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace)
- [GCC/CPP - Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros)